# Transient optional NSSet crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: swift, core-data, exc-bad-access, nsset

I have a transient optional attribute *addedImages* in Swift as part of an one-to-many relationship within a managed object with the attribute and the accessor methods:

```
…
@NSManaged public var addedImages: NSSet?
…
@objc(addAddedImagesObject:)
@NSManaged public func addToAddedImages(_ value: MMImage)

@objc(removeAddedImagesObject:)
@NSManaged public func removeFromAddedImages(_ value: MMImage)

@objc(addAddedImages:)
@NSManaged public func addToAddedImages(_ values: NSSet)

@objc(removeAddedImages:)
@NSManaged public func removeFromAddedImages(_ values: NSSet)
…
```

The failing code is run within a serial queue and crashes with an *EXC_BAD_ACCESS* error.

```
let backgroundContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.privateQueueConcurrencyType)
backgroundContext.performAndWait {
  print("\(self.addedImages?.count ?? 0) added images")
  self.addToAddedImages(image)
}
```

It works without issues when I rather define *addedImages* as non-transient.
I'm not sure if this is a normal behavior, and how I could fix this.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is `self` a managed object in another context?

Comment: No, it's created within the same private context.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption that a transient attribute would be initialized with nil during the creation and fetch was wrong. When I tried to access *count*, the object was simply not in memory.
I had to add this to *awakeFromFetch* and *awakeFromInsert*, which works.

```
if self.addedImages == nil {
  self.addedImages = nil
}
```